# Distinguish between two solutions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio solution (in C#), call it MyProject. I use GIT for version control. I went into GIT and did an Archive Version so as to compare the current code with a previous revision. I have both solutions open in Visual Studio. I want to know if there is any easy way to distinguish between the two solutions in Visual studio. The Publish version is the same. At the top, in the title bar of Visual Studio, both show "My Project - Microsoft Visual Studio". I was looking to maybe add a label to the solution. Right clicking on the 
solution for Properties, I don't see anything. Any suggestions?

Edit:
I see a Git tag was added to the question. That's fine, but this is ultimately a Visual Studio question. I can indeed add a tag to a revision in Git, but this is not reflected in Visual Studio.

Comment: You would have to rename one of the solutions. Just rename the archive one, after all, you're not going to commit any changes from it to git.

Comment: I can´t iamgine why you need to have a historic and the current revision of your solution open. If you´re interested on the changes between the two revision just use any diff-tool, as the solutions are just xml-files that are easy to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into the change window title extension.  You can include part of the path in the window title.

See here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle